# What does this name mean? (Characters identified: 善任)

Tags: translation, meaning, character-identification, names

I would love to know its meaning.
Thank you in anticipation. <3

[image]

The characters represent my adopted daughter's first name, as assigned by her great uncle.

Comment: I edited in the transcription, and the characters can be looked up in a dictionary, such as [善](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=善) and [任](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=任).  Names can generally be made up of any random characters the person (or their parents) want.  (Note that 任 can also be a surname, but then it would be the first character in the name.)  Is there anything you'd want to know beyond this?  Otherwise the question is unlikely to be helpful for others, and probably should be closed.

Comment: I don't think there's much more we're able to say here---the background to this name might not be apparent from the characters.  Perhaps it's a combination of [善良](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=善良) = "kindhearted" and [仁慈](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=仁慈) = "benevolent", but perhaps it's something else.

Answer (score 1):

It could mean 善于任用，good at picking (the right) people!

知人善任：know which person to place in which position.

有些经理认为难以做到知人善任。
Some managers find it hard to delegate.